# Which library would provide the easiest OAuth 2.0 authentication for Sinatra

Tags: ruby, oauth, sinatra

I'm going to implement a simple REST API wrapper around a service and would like to use Ruby with Sinatra for this task.
The Idea is to have users authenticate / sign requests using two-legged OAuth (2.0).

Should I try to use an authentication framework like warden and an addtional oauth 2.0 addon (e.g. [warden-oauth2](https://github.com/opperator/warden-oauth2)) or should I use a rack based solution like [rack-oauth2-server](https://github.com/demandforce/rack-oauth2-server). The rack based approach seems to rely on MongoDB which is ok, but I'd rather minimize the dependencies.

Cheers,
Marc

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [oauth2-provider](https://github.com/songkick/oauth2-provider). Another popular option is [doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper) (rails only).